# как передать переменную в функцию js

Tags: javascript

Нужно каждый раз вызывать функцию с новой переменной namePath, а оно выдает ошибку.
Вот такой код есть:

```
function createNewPath(namePath,[...arr],color) {
  let namePath = new Path2D()
  namePath.rect([0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
  namePath.closePath()
  ctx.fillStyle = `${color}`;
  ctx.fill(namePath)
  ctx.stroke(namePath)
}
```

вызов функции

```
createNewPath(contentPath,[0, height - height / 3, width, height - height / 2],"rgba(43, 41, 41, 1)");
createNewPath(redLine,[0, height - height / 3, width, height - height / 2],"rgba(43, 41, 41, 1)")
```

Получаю ошибку

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'namePath' has already been declared

и такую

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: В том что нужно каждый раз вызывать функцию с новой переменной namePath, а оно выдает ошибку.

Comment: То есть теперь надо из вас вытаскивать текст ошибки

Comment: index.html:230 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'contentPath' before initialization
    at background.onload

Comment: Я немного переписал код

Comment: У функции уже есть аргумент **namePath**, а Вы внутри функции объявляете переменную с таким же именем, о чём, собственно, и говорит ошибка _Identifier 'namePath' has already been declared_

Answer (score 1):

```
 namePath.rect([0]
               ^^^^
```

Что это за ноль такой? Обращение к вселенной?))

---

> Cannot access 'contentPath' before initialization at background.onload –
> Павло Смолинець
> 7 минут назад

Означает, что переменная наверное константа и создана **ПОСЛЕ** обращения к ней, а надо создавать и инициализировать **ДО** обращения

---

> Identifier 'namePath' has already been declared

Тут итак всё ясно, `namePath` **ужЕ**  объявлен в параметрах функции, а вы внутри пытаетесь это сделать ещё раз через `let namePath`

Comment: Обращение ко вселенной это конечно мощно :)

Comment: @rusgeli что-то пишу в комментах - пишут "ответы в ответы, а не в комменты", пишу ответ, пишут - "комменты в комменты а не в ответы" :DDD

Comment: Дополнение: `Cannot access 'contentPath' ...`, также переменная могла быть объявлена через `let`, это особенность ES6+ синтаксиса, вы не можете обращаться к переменной перед тем как она была объявлена. В отличие от `var` где вы можете обращаться к ней перед декларацией, но она будет возвращать `undefined`. `Identifier 'namePath' ...`, скорее всего вы пытаетесь переписать переменную, чтобы это сделать нужно убрать ключевое солово для декларации (`let` / `var`), чтобы в конечном итоге получилось `namePath = ...`, то есть без ключевого слова для декларации переменной. (не релевантно к `const`)

Comment: index.html:230 Uncaught ReferenceError: contentPath is not defined
    at background.onload

Comment: @ПавлоСмолинець Считаю вам надо прочитать книги по базам языка. Если читали - то перечитать снова и переознакомиться. По каждой точке с запятой писать вопросы не имеет никакого смысла

Comment: Сейчас я правильно сформулирую

Comment: Хочу, чтобы не нужно было объявлять переменную, а она объявлялась в среде и передавать ее как переменную.

Comment: @ПавлоСмолинець также обращу внимание, что вопросы-ответы на ruSO должны соблюдать правило: один вопрос - один ответ, а динамически один и тот же  топик редактировать под разные виды проблем - нельзя. Потому что в итоге ответ, который уже дан, будет явно не на тот вопрос. Поэтому текущий вопрос я откачу, а если возникает новый - то создавайте новый